# Accessing SQLite database from multiple processes and SQLITE_BUSY

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, sqlite

I have multiple processes (c++, Windows 8) that use the same SQLite database. I configured connections with `SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED` and `PRAGMA busy_timeout = 60000;`. Used journaling mode - `DELETE`.

Test scenario:

- process #1 opens connection, makes reads/writes, sleeps for 5 sec
- process #2 opens connection, makes reads/writes

After that process #1 failed to write to the database - it receives `SQLITE_BUSY` immediate after call to SQLite API (sqlite3_step, sqlite3_finalize). Process #2 still uses the connection without any problems.

I do not have any not closed transactions, I do not have any long operations on the database. What else can lead to this?

I use the same SQLite connection from the multiple threads inside the process. SQLite docs says that this is OK with config option  `SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED`. Any exception for this rule?

Comment: I'm not sure about the usefulness of `SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED`; it seems to me that with it, the threads that share the database will stomp over each other's transactions. Usually the way it's done is to give each thread their own connection, which has saner semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite acquires lock on database/table in `sqlite3_prepare` and releases it in `sqlite3_finalize`. Type of lock depends on your SQL expression.

If you created an STMT - you need to execute it and finalize as soon as possible. Otherwise you block different connections.

My applications created list of prepared STMT and kept it until the end. Generally this is misuse of SQLite.

Links:

- [SQLite locking](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)

Comment: This is unfortunately wrong. The locks aren't acquired in `sqlite3_prepare`. And you can use `sqlite3_reset` to release the locks (*A statement finishes when its prepared statement is reset or finalized.* - https://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), so you don't need to `sqlite3_finalize` ASAP.